# How to get size of root && used size of root

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I am working with the Google Drive API using the Google PHP client Library.  I am trying to find the current size of the Root directory.

My code is as follows.

```
$file = $this->service->files->get('root',array( 'fields'=>'size,spaces,quotaBytesUsed',));
```

Size and quotaBytesUsed are 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[File resource documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files)

> **size**  long    The size of the *`file's`* content in bytes. This is only
>   applicable to files with binary content in Drive.
>   **quotaBytesUsed** long The number of storage quota bytes used by the *`file`* . This includes the head revision as well as previous revisions with keepForever enabled.

As the documentation states only files contain sizes.  Your going to have to do it the hard way I think and get a list of all the files in your google drive and add them up.

Alternative if you are trying to get info on how much space you have used on google drive you can use the [About.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/about/get) method which returns space for a users google drive account

```
"storageQuota": {
  "limit": "18253611008",
  "usage": "12738688521",
  "usageInDrive": "2449392360",
  "usageInDriveTrash": "838401665"
   }
```